# SIFR3 & jQuery for a styleswitcher script, need a last tip please! ;o)

Tags: sifr

I spent a lot of time trying to configure a styleswitcher script that replace my html background and css from one color to another, I got some texts using SIFR3, mainly h1, h2 tahs and h2 a: links...

My only problem is that when I'm switching, the flash text doesnt take the color change into consideration, I've tried to play with rollBack but I'm out of luck.

I found an interessant solution here :

```
function changeColor(hexValue) {
  var css = '.sIFR-root { color: ' + hexValue + '; }';
  for (var i = 0; i < sIFR.replacements['h1'].length; i++) {
    sIFR.replacements['h1'][i].changeCSS(css);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < sIFR.replacements['h2'].length; i++) {
    sIFR.replacements['h2'][i].changeCSS(css);
  }
}

// after switching stylesheet:
changeColor('#FF9900');
```

It works for h1, h2 but not for my h2 a: links...
Can you tell me how to adjust this?? It would be really really nice.

Right now when firing this function, my links just turn in their old html look with underline text decoration. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the new (or existing) styles for the `a` as well.